# In C, given a series of bytes, how do I copy one byte and then duplicate that byte?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

One of my homework problems is to take a given series of bytes, represented in an unsigned int, and then duplicate a certain byte, thus extending the series by one byte. For example, if I were to perform this function on the unsigned integer represented hexadecimally as 0xAABBCC, while specifying that the second byte be extended, then outputting the hexadecimal value before and after this function would look like so:

```
0xAABBCC -> 0xAABBBBCC
```

I've made some progress as I feel that I do understand bitwise operators well, but I fail to see how to use bitwise operators to perform more complicated tasks like this one. Seeing as this is a homework question, I am open to the answers simply being links to articles on bitwise operators, but just keep in mind that I do have the basics down and that I would prefer to see some real examples of a series of bitwise operations in action.

Here's the code that I have so far. It seems to be close to working, but I just can't grasp how to insert the duplicated byte into the middle of the series of bytes.

```
unsigned long long extend_byte(unsigned x, unsigned i) //x = 0xAABBCC, i = 1
{
    printf("%x\n", x); //0xaabbcc
    int shiftVal = i << 3;
    unsigned mask = 0xFF << shiftVal;
    printf("%x\n", mask); //0x00ff
    unsigned byteToCopy = x | ~mask;
    printf("%x\n", byteToCopy); //0xffffbbff
    x &= byteToCopy;
    printf("%x\n", x); //aabbcc
    return x;
}
```

Comment: How are you counting bytes?  Is the least significant byte counted as byte 1?  If byte 1 was to be replicated, would the result be 0xAABBCCCC?  If byte 3 was to be replicated, would the result be 0xAAAABBCC?  And if byte 4 was to be replicated, there'd be no change?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler They're indexed starting at 0 from the right hand side. In my example, byte 0 corresponds to CC, byte 1 to BB, and byte 2 to AA. It is assumed that an out of index byte won't be given.

Comment: Your example (2nd byte replicates 0x00AABBCC to 0xAABBBBCC) doesn't match the specification in your comment (LSB is byte 0).  You're replicating byte 1 with the sample values, despite stating that you're replicating byte 2.

Comment: Also, your function signature is a bit peculiar.  You take in an `unsigned`, and you manipulate that `unsigned` value, and then return it, claiming that it will be an `unsigned long long` on return.  It will be a 4-byte integer zero padded to 8 bytes that is returned; the leading byte of `x` will not be preserved for any valid shift.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler yes I realize how that was confusing, but I meant second byte as in byte[1] where the index starts at 0. And the function signature was given to me just like that, but are you saying that casting x to a signed long long would preserve the leading byte? Because from what I understand, that is what would happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your mask is masking a single byte, you need to mask all numbers to the right of the byte you want to copy, and with a different mask, mask all the numbers to the left of that byte. Check below:

```
uint64_t extend_byte(uint64_t x, uint64_t i)       // 0x0000000011223344 and 3
{
    uint64_t allOnes = ~0x00ULL;                   // 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

    uint64_t shiftVal = i << 3;                    // i << 3 == i * 8 == 24 bits = 3 bytes
    uint64_t leftMask = allOnes << shiftVal;       // 0xFFFFFFFFFF000000
    uint64_t leftPart = (x << 8) & leftMask;       // 0x0000001122000000
    uint64_t rightMask = ~leftMask;                // 0x0000000000FFFFFF
    uint64_t rightPart = x & ~rightMask;           // 0x0000000000223344

    return leftPart | rightPart;                   // 0x0000001122223344
}
```

I think the trick for solving this kind of problems is to do it step by step and use all the leading zeroes, so you can see how the bytes are moving.

Comment: `uint8` is extremely confusing. Why not use standard `uint64_t`? Also you don't even need 8 bytes for this, 4 would do.

Comment: Note that `~0x00` will be `0xFFFFFFFF` on most systems (because 0x00 is an `int`, and that occupies 4 bytes, and therefore so does `~0x00`).  You'd need `~0x00ULL` to get `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: `leftPart = (x << 8) | leftMask;`  you are doing OR operation, that will add all leading FF's to the left part rom leftMask, I think you are supposed to do AND operation to filter out those leading FF from leftMask, Same is applicable in rightpart.

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful solution. Looking at each line, I understand how it all works, but there is no way I ever would have arrived at this on my own. Can you recommend any resources for practicing more advanced bitwise techniques such as this one so that can practice and am not caught off guard later on during the semester?

Comment: Actually there is one thing I don’t understand. In line 6 why are you shifting by 8 in particular? How would I decide what to shift by here?

Comment: Also, I was just now able to test your code, and it doesn't work. The end result is 0x0000000000000044. Both leftmask and leftpart evaluate to all 0's, and the right mask evaulates to 0x00000000000000FF.

Comment: @Ash Thanks, I did the edit (that's what I get for not testing this first on my computer)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks

Comment: @jburn7 I did some edits because there was a pair of `|` instead of `&` and there was a missing `ULL` too. Did you use the latest code?

Comment: About line 6, I shift by 8 so I can later use the masks to keep two versions of the same byte. If I don't shift, then the two versions of the same byte will be at the same position, and masks will not help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I came up with.  The majority of the thinking is explained in the comments.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
** Given input value = 0x00AABBCC,
** for i = 0, output = 0xAABBCCCC
** for i = 1, output = 0xAABBBBCC
** for i = 2, output = 0xAAAABBCC
**
** There's a RHS, MID and LHS section.
** The MID section corresponds to the byte to be replicated.
** The RHS section corresponds to the (possibly empty) set of bytes to be
**     left unchanged -- the bytes to the right of the mid section.
** The LHS section corresponds to the more significant bytes to the left
**     of the mid section.
**
** Zero bytes in RHS section: (input & ~rhs_mask)
** Shift the result to the left: (input & ~rhs_mask) << 8
** Insert the MID and RHS sections once more:
**     ((input & ~rhs_mask) << 8) | (input & (mid_mask & rhs_mask))
**
** For i = 0:
**    rhs_mask = 0x00000000
**    mid_mask = 0x000000FF
** For i = 1:
**    rhs_mask = 0x000000FF
**    mid_mask = 0x0000FF00
** For i = 2:
**    rhs_mask = 0x0000FFFF
**    mid_mask = 0x00FF0000
**
** RHS mask corresponds to 'all bits one' shifted left by 8*i, then
** bitwise inverted:  ~((~UINT64_C(0) << (8 * i))
*/

static uint64_t extend_byte(uint64_t input, unsigned i)
{
    assert(i < sizeof(input));
    //printf("Input:    0x%.8" PRIX64 " shift %u\n", input, i);
    uint64_t mid_mask = UINT64_C(0xFF) << (8 * i);
    //printf("Mid mask: 0x%.8" PRIX64 ", mid value = 0x%.8" PRIX64 "\n", mid_mask, input & mid_mask);
    uint64_t rhs_mask = ~((~UINT64_C(0)) << (8 * i));
    //printf("RHS mask: 0x%.8" PRIX64 ", RHS value = 0x%.8" PRIX64 "\n", rhs_mask, input & rhs_mask);
    uint64_t output = ((input & ~rhs_mask) << 8) | (input & (mid_mask | rhs_mask));
    //printf("Output:   0x%.8" PRIX64 "\n", output);
    return output;
}

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t input;

    input = 0x00AABBCC;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("0x%.8" PRIX64 " shift %u = 0x%.8" PRIX64 "\n", input, i, extend_byte(input, i));
    putchar('\n');

    input = 0x88776655FFEEDDCC;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        printf("0x%.8" PRIX64 " shift %u = 0x%.8" PRIX64 "\n", input, i, extend_byte(input, i));
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Example output from the test harness:

```
0x00AABBCC shift 0 = 0xAABBCCCC
0x00AABBCC shift 1 = 0xAABBBBCC
0x00AABBCC shift 2 = 0xAAAABBCC
0x00AABBCC shift 3 = 0x00AABBCC

0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 0 = 0x776655FFEEDDCCCC
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 1 = 0x776655FFEEDDDDCC
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 2 = 0x776655FFEEEEDDCC
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 3 = 0x776655FFFFEEDDCC
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 4 = 0x77665555FFEEDDCC
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 5 = 0x77666655FFEEDDCC
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 6 = 0x77776655FFEEDDCC
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 7 = 0x88776655FFEEDDCC
```

---

AFAICT, Revision 5 of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46357199/15168) by [MondKin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/979505/mondkin) produces incorrect results.  When substituted in place of my version of `byte_extend()`, it produces the output:

```
0x00AABBCC shift 0 = 0xAABBFFCC
0x00AABBCC shift 1 = 0xAABBFF00
0x00AABBCC shift 2 = 0xAABB0000
0x00AABBCC shift 3 = 0xAA000000

0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 0 = 0xFF7777FFFFFFDDCC
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 1 = 0xFF7777FFFFFFDD00
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 2 = 0xFF7777FFFFFF0000
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 3 = 0xFF7777FFFF000000
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 4 = 0xFF7777FF00000000
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 5 = 0xFF77770000000000
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 6 = 0xFF77000000000000
0x88776655FFEEDDCC shift 7 = 0xFF00000000000000
```